# Reclaiming an old school Chromebook

Tags: operating-systems, chromebook

In the middle school I go to, we use chromebooks. They are "managed", so we cannot change or do anything to the laptop we are not allowed to do.

One of my friends recently left the school. Since he owns the chromebook, he has the right to modify, change operating systems, and install unapproved software onto it. Unfortunately, the administration has not "unmanaged" the chromebook, and since all local data was cleared, he has been locked out of using it, despite the fact his family paid for the laptop.

I offered to help him rescue it. I tried to enable developer mode, but the fact that the chromebook is "managed" means I cannot access it.

Our goal was to change the operating systems to make the chromebook more useful, but as previously stated, we failed. Does anyone know another way to change operating systems on the chromebook?

Answer (score 1):

When on the home or log in screen, press ESC, REFRESH, & POWER at the same time. That will bring up a red or yellow exclamation mark. At the first one, press control-D. Then follow the rest of the instructions. If that doesn't work, then I suggest that you press either control-D or ESC-REFRESH-POWER  until it says power wash. Click yes, and when it says that Chrome is restarting, hold control-D. It should say "Entering Developer Mode", and if doesn't, keep trying things with these commands.

Comment: Some mangaged chromebooks disable this feature, so your best chance is trying it. If it dosen't work, you will have to contact the school. See this question : https://superuser.com/questions/1511036/reset-a-managed-chromebook