# Reset a Managed Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I just bought a used Lenovo 300e chromebook and I am trying to enable dev mode. When I do "esc" + "refresh" + "power" and then press "ctrl + d", it says that developer mode has been disabled by the administrator. I don't have an admin and I presume that this chromebook used to be managed by some organization before I bought it.

Is there any way to remove the administrator blocks without contacting the person who sold it to me? I have no reason not to contact the person who I bought it from, but I have a feeling that its going to be a real pain tracking down the admin who controls this chromebook. I have no issues with taking parts out of the chromebook, so if any of you know how to do something like that, feel free to include it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can only chime in with Andrew's answer. Treat it as a stolen device. I never got my hands on such a Chromebook (not interested) nor on the management software (very much interested!). I would assume that it must have some kind of (electronic?) asset tag. On newer models the write protect screw has been replaced with a TPM chip. https://wiki.mrchromebox.tech/Firmware_Write_Protect#Disabling_WP_on_CR50_Devices_via_CCD I'm not an expert in flashing or de-soldering chips. But if I were you and had the option to get my money back or computer fraud I'd choose the first option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This model 99% for sure owned by a school and as such it's under the control of the school IT department.  No reset will change that.  Who ever sold it to you is probably a student who didn't return it (aka stole it).  Your only hope is to get that person to give you your money back.

Comment: That are my thoughts exactly on these kinds of questions. It's pushing the envelope a bit to say that it's stolen, my observation from a country (Germany) that does not use chromebooks in education and where they are also uncommon in businesses is: some one ("IT department") are ordered to setup a higher double digit or triple digit number of chromebooks. They do a rather sloppy job an nobody thinks about the entire life cycle of the product or student privacy, e.g. what happens to the device after it's not in use by the initial organization.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Sh1mmer](https://github.com/MercuryWorkshop/sh1mmer) project, as they update it regularly. I tried the project last year, and it worked in unenrolling the Chromebook and regaining access to developer mode.

```
(Chrome OS v101, Lenovo Chromebook IdeaPad Flex 5i, Codename: lillipup)
```

Useful links / sites:

[Sh1mmer Official Website](https://sh1mmer.me/)

[Sh1mmer Official Github Page](https://github.com/MercuryWorkshop/sh1mmer)

Hope this helps!